# How to make a div hide properly on hover while trying to make a gif also start on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I am pretty new to coding and have pieced some things together. I am trying to make an on hover gif start. The original image is static and when you hover the gif starts to play. I got that working fine but I want an overlay over the static image, like a "hover me" button essentially. When I hover over the overlay it wont start the gif because I am not hovering over the static image. When I do a hover display:none for the overlay it just flickers.

Here is a link to what I have so far:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="overlay">TEST   </div>
    <img src="http://fdfranklin.com/gif1.jpg" alt="" id="static">
</div>
```

(New to stackoverflow so not sure how to show css/JS here is a jsfiddle link)

http://jsfiddle.net/T6GEn/

If you get rid of the overlay div the gif properly plays on hover. I essentially want it just like it is now, you hover and the overlay fades out and starts playing the gif.

Any ideas? All help, greatly appreciated.

Comment: GIF doesn't work in JSFiddle - Chrome 32

Comment: @Paulie_D: Off course they do: http://jsfiddle.net/7t66L/

Comment: Not when I checked the OP's fiddle but OK

Comment: @Paulie_D: Off course OPs fiddle doesn't work and that is the reason for the question in the first place. Nothing to do with the jsFiddle tool or the version of Chrome. When OP switches `jpg` with `gif` the `gif` doesn't start playing and OP would like to know how to get it to start playing after the switch.

Comment: Ah, my error...I misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never hiding the overlay div, and therefore not hovering the gif. Just set the start for when you hover the overlay:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".overlay").hover(
        function()
        {
            $('#static').attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/ytWYljT.gif");
        },
        function()
        {
            $('#static').attr("src", "http://fdfranklin.com/gif1.jpg")
        }
    );  
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T6GEn/1/)

Comment: So,Accept the Answer if it works you,So All can see the solution ..@user3324440

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following. Instead of having only one img, create two, one static and one animated. Hide the animated image by default and only show when you're hovering over the overlay. E.g.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay"><p>TEST</p> </div> 
  <img src="http://fdfranklin.com/gif1.jpg" alt="" id="static">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ytWYljT.gif" alt="" id="animated" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

and then

```
$(".overlay").hover(
  function()
  {
     $("#static").hide();
     $("#animated").show();
  },
  function()
  {
    $("#static").show();
    $("#animated").hide();
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the "hover" event is happening to the OVERLAY div, instead of the #static image now. You'll want to change your JS accordingly:

```
 $('.overlay).hover();
```

See here for a complete solution: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EDnU2/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$(".container").hover(
    function(){
        $(".overlay").fadeOut(300);           
        $(this).find("img").attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/ytWYljT.gif");
    },
    function()      {
        $(this).find("img").attr("src", "http://fdfranklin.com/gif1.jpg");
         $(".overlay").fadeIn(300);
    }
);
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T6GEn/2/)**